# inlineCallbacks for a Protocol.dataReceived in Twisted

Tags: twisted, twisted.internet

I seem to misinterpret the rules of `dataReceived` and `inlineCallbacks`.

More specifically, when I do this:

```py
def dataReceived(self, data):
    self.transport.write('ok')
```

my Protocol really sends the data, but when I do this:

```py
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def dataReceived(self, data):
    a = yield True # this stands for some adbapi call actually
    self.transport.write('ok')
```

I receive nothing, then connection just closes. Nor the defer.returnValue helps here, behaviour is just similar.

Kindly explain.

Comment: I just saw your question on the IRC. As stated there, can you provide a bit more insight into your code? Maybe a simple application that shares resemblance to your actual code.  We can give you better help that way.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a hunch, but I don't think the `dataReceived()` function is expected to return anything, so an `inlineCallbacks` or even returning/yielding a regular `Deferred` won't really "do anything".  Sorry for the ambiguity.  What you probably should do is create a `Deferred` and start a callback chain in your `dataReceived()` function.  For example:

```
def dataReceived(self, data):
    # ...
    deferredObj = adbapi.runQuery('SELECT * FROM ...')    # this returns a Deferred
    deferredObj.addCallback(self.someCallback)            # exec self.someCallback() after query returns
    deferredObj.addErrback(self.anotherCallback, *args, **kwargs)

def someCallback(self, result):
    """
    When the db query returns, do something useful here
    """
    print(result)
```

## Links

- [Twisted Async `adbapi` Example](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/rdbms.html)

Comment: That's what I came up with in the end of that discussion : unpack messages to queue, process the queue with a single deferred one message per time, drop the queue and connection altogether if I find the current message unwanted.